Question on continuum hypothesis
We have the notorious continuum hypothesis (CH).
According to Wikipedia, it states

There is no set whose cardinality is strictly between that of the integers and the real numbers.

Gödel proved that CH is consistent with ZFC axioms, and Cohen proved the opposite of CH is consistent with ZFC axioms using his forcing.
My questions are:

The field between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$

Suppose the continuum hypothesis is disproved. Then, do we know the constructions and properties of the field between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ whose cardinality is different from theirs? Especially can this field be constructed from $\mathbb{Q}$ as $\mathbb{R}$ can be constructed as completion by absolute value?

Propositions deduced from CH

Are there any propositions that are obtained supposing ZFC axioms and continuum axioms, and their opposite propositions are obtained supposing ZFC axioms and denying continuum axioms? Such propositions may be logically equivalent to CH.

The situation for p-adic fields

Roughly speaking, CH states whether a field exists between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ and its cardinality is different from them. How about situations for $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p$? If it exists, can the construction be similar to the construction of the field between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$? (as $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are constructed similarly using absolute value).
Thank you for your answers.

The first question is an easy one. There are as many transcendental numbers in $\mathbb R$ as the real numbers. Take a set of transcendeltal real numbers $S$ of cardinality between that of $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R$. Then the minimal subfield $\mathbb Q(S)$ of $\mathbb R$ containing both $\mathbb Q$ and $S$ has the same cardinality as $S$.

For (3), you should look into the notion of transcendence degree. In short, in ZFC, for every field extension $F/K$ there are sets $S\subseteq F$ such that $F$ is algebraic over $K(S)$ and the elements of $S$ are algebraically independent over $K$. Such an $S$ is called a transcendence basis of $F$ over $K$. When $\min{K,S}\ge\aleph_0$ we have $\lvert F\rvert=\lvert K(S)\rvert=\max{\lvert K\rvert,\lvert S\rvert}$, so in the case of $\Bbb Q_p/\Bbb Q$ we have $\lvert S\rvert=2^{\aleph_0}$. Then you can do more or less the same thing as the other comment does for all cardinals in between.

(although admittedly you can do the same thing as the other comment does directly using the fact that $\lvert \Bbb Q_p\rvert=2^{\aleph_0}$)

What are "continuum axioms"?
